# PHP Undefined array key on existing

Tags: php

I'm dealing with Undefined array key on key that actually exists.
Problem is caused when I'm trying to execute `array_sum($array['number'])`, with error
`

> "Undefined array key "number""

I have a lot of objects in that array, but I'm sure that every object has that key.

I tried it to define it as object key, can't find it as well.

Also tried:

```
foreach ($a as $item) {
            if(!array_key_exists('number', $item)){
                return "do not exists";
            }
        }
```

it's not returning that string.

Comment: please show how your loop relates to array_sum? additionally, you should perhaps just do array_column and then sum the items, vs using a foreach

Comment: I'm not using foreach, I just used foreach to check if there is anywhere that that key doesn't exists. It exists everywhere but still failing in array_sum.

Comment: prove *exists everywhere*, your not showing us the array

Comment: Array is 2000 lines. I checked with the code in the description of the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sum = 0;
foreach ($array as $item) {
    $sum += $item->number;
}
```

or

```
$numbers = array_column($array, 'number');
$sum = array_sum($numbers);
```